# Lumen - Service Provider - Rebinding during unit test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, lumen

I have the following on my bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->bind(Auth0\SDK\JWTVerifier::class, function ($app) {
  return new Auth0\SDK\JWTVerifier([
      'supported_algs' => ['RS256'],
      'valid_audiences' => [
        getenv('AUTH0_AUDIENCE'),
        getenv('AUTH0_AUDIENCE_WEB_APP'),
        getenv('AUTH0_AUDIENCE_IOS')
    ],
      'authorized_iss' => [ 'https://' . getenv('AUTH0_DOMAIN') .'/']  // ['AUTH0_DOMAIN']
  ]);
});
```

And during one of my tests, I want to replace this bind to a Mock class, so I'm doing this:

```
    $this->app->instance(Auth0\SDK\JWTVerifier::class, $jwt_verifier);
```

But it still binding the first bind. I'm having problems using ServiceProviders to do the $app->bind process too. Not sure if this is related, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebind the binding in the container, something like this has worked for me:

```
$this->app->bind(Auth0\SDK\JWTVerifier::class, function ($app) use ($jwt_verifier) {
        return $jwt_verifier;
});
```

Comment: do you mean editing the container to pass the test?

Comment: Yes, if you are using the container in your tests and want to use a mock, then you'll have to change what's in the container (usually this is the case with Laravel integration/featurest testing). In ideal world services would be injected and then you can inject your mock during the test and not use the container at all.